# Exchange/Powershell - Loop array data and add result in new column and correct order

Tags: arrays, loops, powershell, exchange-server

I'm attempting to add data through a loop to a new third column in an array but I'm out of luck.

I'm locating the data that I need

```
$DL = Get-DistributionGroup -Identity "*" | Select Name,Manag*
```

1. Name
2. ManagedBy

I attempt to loop through it, successfully, but I have no idea on how to add a new field here and then input it in the correct position...

```
$DL.Name | ForEach-Object {$DL.Members += Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_ | Select Name}
```

1. Name
2. ManagedBy
3. Members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Exchange cmdlets, but I think you could use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for this:

```
$DL = Get-DistributionGroup -Identity '*' | Select-Object Name, Manag*, @{
    Name = 'Members'
    Expression = {Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_ | Select-Object Name}
}
```